# Setting codeigniter routes for language path

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, internationalization, codeigniter-routing

So I am using a [Codeigniter 2.1 Internationalization i18n Library](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n) and I need to adapt my routes to use the language parameters in my short urls where I remove the controller's name:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";

#$route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
#$route['^(en|es|ro)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['results$']      = "fetch/results";
$route['video/(:any)']  = "fetch/video/$1";
$route['tag/(:any)']    = "fetch/tag/$1";

$route['404_override'] = '';
```

So I need to make this work `http://localhost/app/en/results?query=t-shirts` instead of `http://localhost/app/en/fetch/results?query=t-shirts`

How can I accomplish that?

Edit:

```
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$'] = "fetch/results";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(:any)'] = "fetch/video/$1";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(.+)$'] = $route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$'] = "$2";"fetch/video/$2";
```

None of the above works.

If I do `http://localhost/app/en/fetch/video/asfasf` works perfectly

This doesn't `http://localhost/app/en/video/asfasf`

The error I get is a 404:

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

### Found the problem

So, for some reason having this set : `$route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$'] = "$2";` before what I was trying to do was causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anybody that uses that library and wants to set custom routes, in order for them to work you'll have to do it in this order:

1. custom routes
2. The routes added by the library

example:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";

//First
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(.+)$'] = "fetch/video/$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$']     = "fetch/results$2";
//Second
$route['^(en|es|ro)/(.+)$']        = "$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)$'] = $route['default_controller'];


$route['404_override']  = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of defeats the purpose of controllers, but if you know that anything with "results" as the second segment should use the "fetch" controller, you could do this:

```
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$'] = "fetch/results";
```

**EDIT:**

It's because your `(:any)` line is catching before the right one.  Also, a "." (dot) character will match a forward slash too, which probably isn't what you want.

```
$route['^(en|es|ro)/results$']       = "fetch/results";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/([^/]+)$'] = "fetch/video/$2";
$route['^(en|es|ro)/video/(:any)']   = "fetch/video/$1";
```

Comment: will let you know the results as soon as I get a chance to test it. tnx

Comment: tnx, I changed the system but tnx anyway

Comment: Back to the old system (for seo reasons), tried your suggestion but doesn't work

Comment: Is your base_url config set to `http://localhost/app/`?  If not, you'll need your route to be `$route['^app/(en|es|ro)/results$'] = "fetch/results"`

Comment: yes it is, the `base_url` isn't the problem. It redirects correctly to `http://localhost/app/en/result?query=data` or whatever, but errors out

Comment: Yes, but watch out for `(.+)$` doing the same thing as `(:any)`

Comment: Gotcha.  Glad you figured it out.